# 2 options in navigation using radio male or female

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I hover the mouse for the navigation instead of linking to `maleF.html` or `femaleF.html` it will open my folder name formal where my img photos are stored.

**radio male female**

```
    <form style="padding-top:0px">
    <input type="text" name="search" oninput="myFunction()" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female

   </form>
```

**navigation**

```
<div class = "dropdown" width = "10">
    <button class="dropbtn">Clothing</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a id="formal" href="#formal">Formal</a></br>
        <a id="maleFormal" style="display:none" href="maleaF.html">Male Formal</a>
        <a id="femaleFormal" style="display:none" href="formalF.html">Female Formal</a>
            <a href="#tshirt">Tshirt</a></br>
            <a href="#jeans">Jeans</a></br>
            <a href="#skirts">Skirts</a></br>
            <a href="#shorts">Shorts</a></br>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','#male',function(){ // this is to fitch male html. script
$("#formal").hide();
$("#maleFormal").hide();
$("#femaleFormal").show();
});
$(document).on('click','#female',function(){ // this is fitch female.html script
    $("#formal").hide();
    $("#maleaFormal").hide();
    $("#femaleFormal").show();
                });
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It suppose to open either male or female.html but instead it will be reroute to my folder name formal. I cant figure out what went wrong to my code

Comment: <a id="formal" href="#formal">Formal</a></br><=== href="#formal" what will u used here for my js to do its working for sorting out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please add "male" and "female" id attribute inside radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male"> Male
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female"> Female
```

Then change your jquery code to something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#male").click(function(){ // this is to fitch male html. script
        $("#formal").hide();
        $("#maleFormal").show();
        $("#femaleFormal").hide();
    });
    $("#female").click(function(){ // this is fitch female.html script
        $("#formal").hide();
        $("#maleaFormal").hide();
        $("#femaleFormal").show();
    });
});
</script>
```